# Improvement of table

Tags: tables

How to delete vertical line except the second one (like on the picture) and center all text in head in vertical and horizontal direction? Thank you
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set suitable page parameters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern,tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\newcommand\mytab[1]{%
   \bgroup%
   \setlength\extrarowheight{0pt}%
   \smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}} #1 \end{tabular}}%
   \egroup}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{regexpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchparametertext\@cline{-}{\cA-}{}{}
\makeatother
\setlength\textwidth{145mm}
\setlength\textheight{247mm}
\setlength\oddsidemargin{15mm}
\setlength\evensidemargin{15mm}
\setlength\topmargin{0mm}
\setlength\headsep{0mm}
\setlength\headheight{0mm}
\let\openright=\clearpage

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht!]
\scriptsize
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}  % default: 6pt
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{5}{C|} >{\hsize=1.3\hsize}C| >{\hsize=0.7\hsize}C| *{3}{C|}}
\hline
Veličina & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{M} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{C} & R & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{P} \\
\cline{2-10}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{PHOEBE fotometrie a RV} & 
\mytab{POWR\\analýza} & 
\mytab{Řešení\\světelných\\křivek a RV} & 
CFF & & \\
\cline{2-4}
& Řešení I & Řešení II & Řešení III & & & & Model malá hmotnost & Model střední hmotnost & Model velká hmotnost\\
\hline\hline
& & & & & & & & & \\
& & & & & & & & & \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Off-topic: Instead of `\multicolumn{1}{|c}{Veličina}`, just write `Veličina`.

Comment: Hint: In the second argument of `tabularx`, change `*{5}{|C}` to `|*{5}{C|}`.

Comment: Thank you and centering please?

Comment: Dear Elisabeth, you ask the almost the same question again and again. it is time, that you beside your primary occupation analyse all received answer and suggestion and learn something from it. on similar question (actually on the same) already receive answers for the same problem. sorry, it is not clear what is your problem ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I propose two consecutive tabularx for the problem with vertical lines. As to the column heads centring, I propose a slightly diferent layout (‘Mod"el is common to the last three columns) and  I replaced `\mytab` with `\multirowcell`from the `makecell` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2.5cm, nohead]{geometry} % set suitable page parameters
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern,tabularx,ragged2e, multirow, makecell}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{regexpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchparametertext\@cline{-}{\cA-}{}{}
\makeatother
\let\openright=\clearpage

\begin{document}

   \begin{table}[ht!]
    \scriptsize
    \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{2pt} % default: 6pt
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{5}{C|}>{\hsize=1.3\hsize}C| >{\hsize=0.7\hsize}C| *{3}{C|}}
    \hline
    \multirowcell{4}{Veličina} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{M} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{C} & R & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{P} \\
    \cline{2-10}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{PHOEBE fotometrie a RV} &
    \multirowcell{3}{POWR\\analýza} &
 \multirowcell{3}{Řešení\\světelných\\křivek a RV} &
    \multirowcell{2}{CFF }& \multicolumn{3}{c|}{ Model } \\
    \cline{2-4}\cline{8-10}
    & Řešení I & Řešení II & Řešení III & & & & malá hmotnost & střední hmotnost & velká hmotnost \\
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}\vskip 0.3ex
     \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{C|*{5}{C} >{\hsize=1.3\hsize}C >{\hsize=0.7\hsize}C *{3}{C}}
 \hline
 & & & & & & & & & \\
 & & & & & & & & & \\
 & & & & & & & & & \\
 & & & & & & & & & \\
 \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Other possibility:

```
   \begin{table}[ht!]
    \scriptsize%
    \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{2pt} % default: 6pt
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{5}{C|}>{\hsize=1.6\hsize}C| >{\hsize=0.4\hsize}C| *{3}{C|}}
    \hline
    \multirowcell{4}{Veličina} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{M} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{C} & R & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{P} \\
    \cline{2-10}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{\multirowcell{1.5}{PHOEBE fotometrie a RV}}
     & \multirow{3}{=}{\centering POWR analýza} & %
    \multirow{3}{=}{\centering Řešení světelných křivek a RV} &
    \multirowcell{3}{CFF }& \multirow{3}{=}{\centering Model malá hmotnost} & \multirow{3}{=}{\centering Model střední hmotnost} & \multirow{3}{=}{\centering Model velká hmotnost} \\[1ex]
    \cline{2-4}
    & \multirowcell{1.5}{Řešení I} & \multirowcell{1.5}{Řešení II} &\multirowcell{1.5}{Rešení III} & & & & & &\\ [1.5ex]
    \hline
        \end{tabularx}\vskip 0.3ex
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{C|*{4}{C} >{\hsize=1.3\hsize}C >{\hsize=0.7\hsize}C *{3}{C}}
     \hline
     & & & & & & & & & \\
     & & & & & & & & & \\
     & & & & & & & & & \\
     & & & & & & & & & \\
     \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: Please also replace `\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}` with blank. And, do delete the option `margin=2.5cm` while loading `geometry` — the OP overrides that option with more-specific directives.

Comment: I don't understand. Doesn't the O.P. want to keep all lines in the heads as shown in the post?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I had incorrectly assumed that you had replaced `*{5}{|C}` with `*|{5}{C|}` -- the OP also wants (I think!) a vertical divider between the two cells below the two-column-wide "C" header.

Comment: Thank you very much. And how is it possible to remove the line under "Model" and write this word to three cells?
   `& Řešení I & Řešení II & Řešení III & & & & Model malá hmotnost & Model střední hmotnost & Model velká hmotnost \\` I damage it when I am trying to do that

Comment: @Elisabeth: I'll try to see that. A common ‘Model’ was the easiest solution.

Comment: @Elisabeth: I've added another solution, whichhoefully  will be more like you want.